# Purpose of QP in SVM and Issues in High Memory Usage

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am learning **Sequential Minimal Optimization(SMO)** for text categorization. Most of the SMO related references says that General SVM leads to large memory usage while using **QP** problem to train samples.Then I started to learn **QP**. But I could not understand how **QP** leads to large memory usage while training samples with SVM and ***what is the purpose of QP in SVM***. Can any one please clear my doubt with some **Real time example**?.. Thanks in advance...